# Any way to swap rows and columns in pgfplotstable?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I've got a simple table that's made by pgfplotstable by pulling from a fairly large csv file.
The table is vertical like the data provided but since it's only two columns, and several rows I'd rather it be transposed to a horizontal format.
Here's the table.

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
columns={Item,Total},
select equal part entry of={0}{2},
unique={Item}
]{data/responses.csv}
```

I've removed any stylistic options, but left ones that might affect the transposition.

Comment: See \pgfplotstabletranspose (page 63).  You can create a table for a MWE using either \pgfplotstableread or filecontents.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that in the manual. I was only looking in the options for typeset.